# Elementary question on Hausdorff distance: Difference between integrals on level sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, hausdorff-distance

Let $U \subset \mathbb R^2$ be compact and consider

- $h:U \times (0,T) \to \mathbb R$ a uniformly bounded function such that:
  $0 \lt c_1 \le h \le 1-c_2 $
- $f_1,f_2 \in W^{2,1}_p(U \times (0,T))$ for each $p \ge 1$

> I'm trying to understand why:
>
> $\int_{\{x:f_1(x,\cdot) \gt 0\}} (1-h)dy -\int_{\{x:f_2(x,\cdot) \gt
>  0\}} (1-h)dy \le Cd_H(\{x:f_1(x,\cdot) \gt 0\},\{x:f_2(x,\cdot) \gt
>  0\})(*)$
>
> where $d_H(\{x:f_1(x,\cdot) \gt 0\},\{x:f_2(x,\cdot) \gt 0\})$ denotes
>   the Hausdorff distance

As I see it,

$\int_{\{x:f_1(x,\cdot) \gt 0\}} (1-h)dy -\int_{\{x:f_2(x,\cdot) \gt
 0\}} (1-h)dy \le \\ (1-c_1)\vert \{x:f_1(x,\cdot) \gt 0\} \vert -c_2\vert \{x:f_2(x,\cdot) \gt 0\} \vert (**)$

QUESTIONS:

1. How is $(*)$ related to $(**)$?
2. Why can the Hausdorff distance be defined for the set $\{x:f_i(x,\cdot) \gt 0\}$ since it's not compact?

I'm afraid that my questions are quite trivial and silly but I'm not familiar at all to the Hausdorff distance and its properties. So, I would appreciate any help as well as a good reference in order to study more about this topic.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: A brief [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) on Hausdorff distance.